# Getting error "There was no endpoint listening at ..." while accessing clients URL when website is deployed, but working fine on dev

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I have a windows server 2008 which I had deployed my website that accesses clients API just fine, due to end of support of Server 2008, we have formatted it to Server 2016 and re-deployed all applications, it was all was running fine until a user tried to access on of our client's API and cannot connect. We can successfully connect to the API when on debug/dev mode, but when accessing through our  deployed website, we always encounter error saying "here was no endpoint listening at https://someurl?wsdl that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details". Im lost.

I already tried installing all IIS Features and backward compatibility, still nothing,

Here is my config for binding.

```
<binding name="IPRNImplPortBinding1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
     receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
     bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
     maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
     textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
     messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide more details, as well as what you have tried to solve this. So you have moved a web application (I assume) from one server to the other, and now the client tells you it can't reach the service. So have you tried browsing to `https://someurl/?wsdl`? What do you see? Have you checked the server's error logs? And so on. We can't say anything about this with this little info.

Comment: I tried to browse https://someurl/?wsdl and was able to access it. And also I can connect to it when Iam on debug mode. Ive tried to solve issues using links below Sorry for the incomplete info on my question. Im new here. Thanks

Comment: So it's probably a proxy or firewall that blocks traffic?

Comment: Do you have ways to check if it is being block by proxy of firewall? thanks soo much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this will help anyone but what solve the problem is adding the hostname of the webservice/api I was trying to connect on the HOST file located at **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc** of the server. I'm not familiar with the host file but it really works like a charm.

Comment: Earlier, I suspect we might need to add an entry to the HOSTS file since there might be something wrong with the network. anyway, Congratulations to you.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I would like to know how you call the Client API in your website project and the complete configuration on the server-side. In my opinion, there might be something wrong with the service endpoint address during the call.
As you know, generally there are two ways to call the `WCF` service, `ChannelFactory` or client proxy. in these two ways, we have to configure some additional settings, service endpoint address, client credential and so on.
Besides, due to the binding with transport security mode, have you established the trust relationship between the client-side and the server-side? We have to install the certificate with each other in the `Local CA`.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: The inner exception says: The remote name could not be resolved: wws.someurl.com. Certificate has been installed already. My real issue is that, before server upgrade, it was running fine, and then come server 2016, suddenly cannot connect. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you test the network connectivity through the domain name by using the Ping command?

Comment: Hellow Abraham Qian, I cannot ping the url the host and hostname cannot be resolve by ping so that's why I tried adding the IP on host file and works like a charm. Thank you